# Alert button in innerhtml

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml, codeigniter-3

I have a javascript function to call this result in a div innerhtml. How to alert 'Alert Function' when button on click?

```
$html.='<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%">#</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
            $c=1;
        foreach($titles AS $item){
            $html.='<tr>
                    <td>'.$c.'</td>
                    <td>'.urldecode($item->title_content).'</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="alert(\'**Alert Function**\')">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>';
                $c++;
        }
        $html.='</tbody>
         </table>';
        echo $html;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your issue with this code?

Comment: Actually above code is called by javascrip and I pass the value to the controller using ajax and then innerhtml view in a div. When it display on div, but the onclick button not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is PHP, you can directly insert `onClick()` event like this:

```
<td><button type="button" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="alertFunction()">Delete</button></td>
```

And then in JavaScript file:

```
function alertFunction()
{
    alert('My custom text');
}
```

Let me know if that solves your problem and if I understood your question correctly.

If this `onClick()` is written in JavaScript itself, then remove that part and add additional line in JavaScript script:

```
document.getElementById("deleteButton").addEventListener("click", alertFunction);
```

Comment: Actually above code is called by javascrip and I pass the value to the controller using ajax and then innerhtml view in a div. When it display on div, but the onclick button not working.

Comment: @MohdHadrulladtfiBinMamat Additionally, you can use `EventListener()` to help avoid raw text instead of function callings. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate function to handle `onclick` event. This will be helpful in future if you want to pass any argument

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="clickButton()">Delete</button></td>
```

Somewhere in your code inside script tag create a function call `clickButton()`

```
function clickButton(){
 alert('Alert Function')
}
```

Comment: Actually above code is called by javascrip and I pass the value to the controller using ajax and then innerhtml view in a div. When it display on div, but the onclick button not working.